# How to save background color in cookie through button click?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Im currently trying to learn about cookies in javascript.

My question is : I have three Button Red-Green-Blue and if i click for example on red, the background color red should be saved within a cookie so that i reload the webpage its colored red.

```
document.cookie ="red";
document.cookie ="green";
document.cookie ="blue";
function BackgroundRed(){
document.cookie = "background-color=red";
}


<button onClick="BackgroundRed()" style="background-color:red">Rot</button>
<button onClick="alertCookie()" style="background-color:green">Grün</button>
<button onClick="alertCookie()" style="background-color:blue">Blau</button>
```

Comment: Please show that you have tried to solve the problem and show any progress.

Comment: why don't you try with localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cookieValue = getCookie('backgroundColor'),
      btns = document.querySelectorAll('.color-btn');

  if (cookieValue) {
    setBackgroundColor(cookieValue);
  }
  
  Array.from(btns).forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
      setBackgroundColor(color);
    });
  });
});

function setBackgroundColor(color) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  setCookie('backgroundColor', color);
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(';'),
      cookie = cookies.find(function(str) { return str.indexOf(name + '=') === 0; });
  if (cookie) {
    return cookie.split('=')[1];
  }
  return null;
}

function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
}
```

```css
body { background: red; }
button { padding: 1em; }
[data-color="red"] { background: red; }
[data-color="blue"] { background: blue; }
[data-color="green"] { background: green; }
```

```html
<button class="color-btn" data-color="red"></button>
<button class="color-btn" data-color="blue"></button>
<button class="color-btn" data-color="green"></button>
```

> **Note**: this demo won't work on Stack Overflow because it is sandboxed and does not accept cookies

**Edit:**

In the example above, I did not set an expiry date on the cookie for clarity. This means that the cookie will only stay during the current session *(i.e. when you close all of your browser's tabs, it will be gone)*. You can choose to keep it for a longer period. For example, a year:

```
var expiry = new Date();
expiry.setFullYear(expiry.getFullYear() + 1);
document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; expires=' + expiry.toUTCString() + ';';
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works but on button click it does not change the color.

Comment: @TimurLüdemann It works here:  http://jsfiddle.net/L7wvrmxk/ . You need to make sure that the DOM _(HTML)_ is fully loaded when this script runs. Try wrapping the first blocks _(from `var cookieValue...` to `Array.from...`)_ with this: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* Paste the code here */ });`. **I edited my answer to reflect that change**

Comment: it works thanks .. but now he jumps back again to only red .. it shouid stay on the background color when reloaded i clicked before the reload .. for example i click green -> reload page -> green is background color

Edit : maybe cause on local it doesnt work ?

Comment: @TimurLüdemann That's because Chrome does not accept cookies on URLs that start with `file:///`. You can put it on a server _(to get a `http/s` url)_, or use Firefox, which allows cookies on local files.

Comment: @blex What is the expiry date of that cookie? Is it set in the code? Or that current script saves it forever till the cookie is gone?  How can it be set for 1 year for example?  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike I've just added this at the end of the answer. Hope this helps

Comment: @blex Thanks a lot..  Upvoted..  I am trying to do the same in php, can you check my question please here, whether using the same same script or the one in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753298/convert-js-to-php-for-background-color-cookie