# Convert js to php for background color cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using the following js script to add a cookie for background color changed by the user, however it takes like half of 1 second to load the color, and I was thinking that using php for the cookie would be better to write the chosen color from the point of loading the page, so it loads with the right color from the start.

**JS**:

```js
var setCookie = function (n, val) {
    var exdays = 30;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = n + "=" + val + "; " + expires;
};

var getCookie = function (n) {
    var name = n + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
};

document.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'color-btn') {
        var favColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
        setCookie('color', favColor);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = favColor;
        console.log(favColor);
    }
};

window.onload = function () {
    var favColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
    var color = getCookie('color');
    if (color === '') {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = favColor;
    } else {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
};
```

```css
      body {
  background-color: rgba(219, 218, 236, 1);
}

.color-btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<li><button class="color-btn" style="background-color: #dbdaec"></button></li>
<li><button class="color-btn" style="background-color: #B4CAE5"></button></li>
<li><button class="color-btn" style="background-color: #C2E5C6"></button></li>
<li><button class="color-btn" style="background-color: #EAEAEA"></button></li>
<li><button class="color-btn" style="background-color: #ffffff"></button></li>
```

*Note: the above script is in sandbox, and won't work here.*

**The converted php** (that is not working):

```
<?php
$setCookie = new Func(function($n = null, $val = null) use (&$Date, &$document) {
  $exdays = 30.0;
  $d = _new($Date);
  call_method($d, "setTime", _plus(call_method($d, "getTime"), to_number($exdays) * 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 1000.0));
  $expires = _concat("expires=", call_method($d, "toGMTString"));
  set($document, "cookie", _concat($n, "=", $val, "; ", $expires));
});
$getCookie = new Func(function($n = null) use (&$document) {
  $name = _concat($n, "=");
  $ca = call_method(get($document, "cookie"), "split", ";");
  for ($i = 0.0; $i < get($ca, "length"); $i++) {
    $c = get($ca, $i);
    while (eq(call_method($c, "charAt", 0.0), " ")) {
      $c = call_method($c, "substring", 1.0);
    }
    if (eq(call_method($c, "indexOf", $name), 0.0)) {
      return call_method($c, "substring", get($name, "length"), get($c, "length"));
    }
  }
  return "";
});
set($document, "onclick", new Func(function($e = null) use (&$setCookie, &$document, &$console) {
  if (eq(get(get($e, "target"), "className"), "color-btn")) {
    $favColor = get(get(get($e, "target"), "style"), "backgroundColor");
    call($setCookie, "color", $favColor);
    set(get(get($document, "body"), "style"), "backgroundColor", $favColor);
    call_method($console, "log", $favColor);
  }
}));
set($window, "onload", new Func(function() use (&$document, &$getCookie) {
  $favColor = get(get(get($document, "body"), "style"), "backgroundColor");
  $color = call($getCookie, "color");
  if ($color === "") {
    set(get(get($document, "body"), "style"), "backgroundColor", $favColor);
  } else {
    set(get(get($document, "body"), "style"), "backgroundColor", $color);
  }

}));
?>
```

Comment: You don't have to write the cookie with PHP. You could leave the JS code as it is, and simply read the value with PHP the next time you load the page, and set the background color according to that value server-side. That being said, I could do it in PHP, but my knowledge is limited and your code looks like chinese to me :) _(... and I don't speak chinese, so... haha)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working simplified version:

```
<?php
$colors = ['#dbdaec', '#B4CAE5', '#C2E5C6', '#EAEAEA', '#ffffff'];
// Default color
$color = $colors[4];
// Try to read the cookie
if(isset($_COOKIE["color"])) {
  // If it exists, set the color to its value
  $color = $_COOKIE["color"];
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body { background-color: <?=$color?>; } /* Here, use the color */
  .color-btn {
    width: 100px; height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid white;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul><?php foreach ($colors as $c) { ?>
      <li><button class="color-btn" style="background-color: <?=$c?>"></button></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <script>
  // I did not edit your JS other than remove unused blocks
  var setCookie = function (n, val) {
    var exdays = 30;
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = n + "=" + val + "; " + expires;
  };
  document.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'color-btn') {
      var favColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
      setCookie('color', favColor);
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = favColor;
      console.log(favColor);
    }
  };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It uses JS to set the cookie client-side, so that the page does not reload. And the next time you reload the page or go to another, PHP will read that cookie and set that background color server-side so that there is no color flash.

Comment: Thanks, how can I set add the option for the user to choose the color, same as your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53904771/1114465 with php and expiry date?  Can you please edit this answer to that?

Comment: Great.. but why does it reload the page when the color is chosen?  The other example I guess using jquery changes the color on click..  or that can't be done in this case?

Comment: You want to set the cookie in PHP. Since PHP is executed in the backend, you either need to reload the page, or send the color with Ajax. I'll create an example using Ajax.

Comment: Actually, no, I won't create an example using Ajax. The first answer I posted here was correct. It sets the cookie in JS (so, without reloading the page), and then when you reload the page, PHP is used to read the cookie. I'll put that answer back

Comment: I tried to test again in a fiddle and it does reload the page: http://main.xfiddle.com/code_50964467.php I tried removing `type="submit"` but same issue, I thinks because of `action="" method="POST"`.

Comment: @Mike I edited my answer, using my first answer, along with your JS code (from which I removed the `getCookie` function and the `window.onload` listener)

Answer (score 0):

To set a cookie in PHP:

```
setcookie("bgcolor", $value, time()+3600);
```

to get a cookie in PHP and run a quick validation to make sure there isn't anything that shouldn't be in there.

```
$bgcolor = $_COOKIE["bgcolor"];
if(ctype_xdigit(substr($bgcolor ,1)) == false || strlen(ltrim($bgcolor ,"#"))!=6){
   $bgcolor = "#ffffff";
}
```

to output that variable to the screen:

```
<?=bgcolor?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you edit the above code with your suggestion?  I am not sure where to edit these lines..